# select range when value is higher than in previous value

Tags: mysql, trend, forex

How to get all records where value is higher than previous value.
For example, first range in the table below start on id 1 and ends on id 6, next range is from 7 to 10, etc...

```
id  Open
1   1.30077
2   1.30088
3   1.30115
4   1.30132
5   1.30135
6   1.30144
7   1.30132
8   1.30137
9   1.30152
10  1.30158
11  1.30149
12  ...
```

Comment: Are the IDs guaranteed to be sequential, or does it have to deal with gaps?

Answer (score 2):

## YOUR SAMPLE DATA

```
USE test
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS rangedata;
CREATE TABLE rangedata
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  open FLOAT
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
INSERT INTO rangedata (open) VALUES
(1.30077),(1.30088),(1.30115),(1.30132),
(1.30135),(1.30144),(1.30132),(1.30137),
(1.30152),(1.30158),(1.30149),
(1.30077),(1.30088),(1.30115),(1.30132),
(1.30135),(1.30144),(1.30132),(1.30137),
(1.30152),(1.30158),(1.30149),
(1.30077),(1.30088),(1.30115),(1.30132),
(1.30135),(1.30144),(1.30132),(1.30137),
(1.30152),(1.30158),(1.30149);
```

## YOUR SAMPLE DATA LOADED

```
mysql>     USE test
Database changed
mysql>     DROP TABLE IF EXISTS rangedata;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql>     CREATE TABLE rangedata
    ->     (
    ->       id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ->       open FLOAT
    ->     ) ENGINE=MyISAM;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)

mysql>     INSERT INTO rangedata (open) VALUES
    ->     (1.30077),(1.30088),(1.30115),(1.30132),
    ->     (1.30135),(1.30144),(1.30132),(1.30137),
    ->     (1.30152),(1.30158),(1.30149),
    ->     (1.30077),(1.30088),(1.30115),(1.30132),
    ->     (1.30135),(1.30144),(1.30132),(1.30137),
    ->     (1.30152),(1.30158),(1.30149),
    ->     (1.30077),(1.30088),(1.30115),(1.30132),
    ->     (1.30135),(1.30144),(1.30132),(1.30137),
    ->     (1.30152),(1.30158),(1.30149);
Query OK, 33 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 33  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>
```

## QUERY USING JOINS

Here is the LEFT JOIN query

```
SET @grp = 1;
SELECT A.open prev,(@grp:=@grp+IF(A.open<B.open,1,0)) group_number
FROM rangedata A LEFT JOIN rangedata B ON A.id= B.id+1;
```

Here is its output

```
mysql> SELECT A.open prev,(@grp:=@grp+IF(A.open<B.open,1,0)) group_number
    -> FROM rangedata A LEFT JOIN rangedata B ON A.id= B.id+1;
+---------+--------------+
| prev    | group_number |
+---------+--------------+
| 1.30088 |            1 |
| 1.30115 |            1 |
| 1.30132 |            1 |
| 1.30135 |            1 |
| 1.30144 |            1 |
| 1.30132 |            2 |
| 1.30137 |            2 |
| 1.30152 |            2 |
| 1.30158 |            2 |
| 1.30149 |            3 |
| 1.30077 |            4 |
| 1.30088 |            4 |
| 1.30115 |            4 |
| 1.30132 |            4 |
| 1.30135 |            4 |
| 1.30144 |            4 |
| 1.30132 |            5 |
| 1.30137 |            5 |
| 1.30152 |            5 |
| 1.30158 |            5 |
| 1.30149 |            6 |
| 1.30077 |            7 |
| 1.30088 |            7 |
| 1.30115 |            7 |
| 1.30132 |            7 |
| 1.30135 |            7 |
| 1.30144 |            7 |
| 1.30132 |            8 |
| 1.30137 |            8 |
| 1.30152 |            8 |
| 1.30158 |            8 |
| 1.30149 |            9 |
| 1.30077 |            9 |
+---------+--------------+
33 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

## QUERY WITHOUT JOINS

Using user-defined variables, you simply monitor each row and see when the previous value is greater. Ready for the query? Here it is:

```
SET @prev = '0.00000';
SET @grp = 1;
SELECT id,open,(@grp:=@grp+increasing) group_number FROM
(SELECT id,open,IF(@prev<=open,0,1) increasing,(@prev:=open) FROM rangedata) A;
```

Here is your sample data tripled:

Here is the query's execution:

```
mysql> SET @prev = '0.00000';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @grp = 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT id,open,(@grp:=@grp+increasing) group_number FROM
    -> (SELECT id,open,IF(@prev<=open,0,1) increasing,(@prev:=open) FROM rangedata) A;
+----+---------+--------------+
| id | open    | group_number |
+----+---------+--------------+
|  1 | 1.30077 |            1 |
|  2 | 1.30088 |            1 |
|  3 | 1.30115 |            1 |
|  4 | 1.30132 |            1 |
|  5 | 1.30135 |            1 |
|  6 | 1.30144 |            1 |
|  7 | 1.30132 |            2 |
|  8 | 1.30137 |            2 |
|  9 | 1.30152 |            2 |
| 10 | 1.30158 |            2 |
| 11 | 1.30149 |            3 |
| 12 | 1.30077 |            4 |
| 13 | 1.30088 |            4 |
| 14 | 1.30115 |            4 |
| 15 | 1.30132 |            4 |
| 16 | 1.30135 |            4 |
| 17 | 1.30144 |            4 |
| 18 | 1.30132 |            5 |
| 19 | 1.30137 |            5 |
| 20 | 1.30152 |            5 |
| 21 | 1.30158 |            5 |
| 22 | 1.30149 |            6 |
| 23 | 1.30077 |            7 |
| 24 | 1.30088 |            7 |
| 25 | 1.30115 |            7 |
| 26 | 1.30132 |            7 |
| 27 | 1.30135 |            7 |
| 28 | 1.30144 |            7 |
| 29 | 1.30132 |            8 |
| 30 | 1.30137 |            8 |
| 31 | 1.30152 |            8 |
| 32 | 1.30158 |            8 |
| 33 | 1.30149 |            9 |
+----+---------+--------------+
33 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The key point is this: Every time a new group number appears, that tells you the the next value dropped.

## PLEASE NOTE THE OUTPUT IS IDENTICAL FOR BOTH QUERIES

**CAVEAT**: The second query is not a perfect solution in case there is some floating point issues between `prev` and `open`. If these are ridiculously close to each other, it may not be right. This was best try outside of writing a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Ranges can be numbered using this query:

```
SELECT id, open, range_number
FROM( 
  SELECT *,
         if(@lastopen<open,@grp,@grp:=@grp+1) range_number,
         @lastopen:=open
  FROM table1,
  (select @lastopen:=null,@grp:=0) qqq
  ORDER BY id
) qqq;
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1bb8/9

```
| ID |           OPEN | RANGE_NUMBER |
|----|----------------|--------------|
|  1 | 1.300770044327 |            1 |
|  2 | 1.300879955292 |            1 |
|  3 | 1.301149964333 |            1 |
|  4 | 1.301319956779 |            1 |
|  5 |  1.30134999752 |            1 |
|  6 | 1.301440000534 |            1 |
|  7 | 1.301319956779 |            2 |
|  8 | 1.301370024681 |            2 |
|  9 | 1.301519989967 |            2 |
| 10 |  1.30157995224 |            2 |
| 11 | 1.301489949226 |            3 |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT startid,MAX(id) FROM (
    SELECT 
       @currentid := IF(@previous <= open,@currentid,id) as startid,
       @previous := open,
       id
    FROM ranges 
    JOIN (SELECT @currentid := MIN(id), @previous := MIN(open) FROM ranges) as variables
    ORDER BY id) runningscan
GROUP BY startid ORDER BY startid + 0;
```

See this on SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3cea/3

What this does is: in the runningscan subquery, it runs through the table once, keeping taps if `open` is bigger or smaller then the previous `open` (stored in the `@previous` variable. This gets you a list with all ids, and the id's which started an interrupted higher (or equal) 'run'. From that, we only need to find the highest id for a starting id, so we put it in a subquery for an easy `max` construct. Gaps in the `id` column are no problem. If you a single row can't be a range (i.e: `open` lowers twice or more in succession), add a `WHERE startid < id` clause in the outer query. If you need ranges of a minimum number of rows to qualify is a range of more then 1, add a `HAVING COUNT(*) > your_desired_minimum`.